# translating wget command to restsharp code

Tags: c#, stanford-nlp, restsharp

I try to execute this:

```
wget --post-data 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.' 'localhost:9000/?properties={"annotators":"tokenize,ssplit,pos","outputFormat":"json"}' -O -
```

Taken form [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/caseless.html) into C# RestSharp code. AFIK this is a post request? So I went for this code:

```
var client = new RestClient(@"http://localhost:9000/?properties={""annotators"":""tokenize,ssplit,pos"", ""outputFormat"":""json""}")
{
    Timeout = 5000 
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddBody(@"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

This returns:

```
{
  "sentences": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "tokens": [
        {
          "index": 1,
          "word": "<String />",
          "originalText": "<String />",
          "characterOffsetBegin": 0,
          "characterOffsetEnd": 10,
          "pos": "ADD",
          "before": "",
          "after": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

which is kind of empty. So I assume my translation is somewhat incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you expecting to get returned? What do you get from the wget command?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the issue was the missing DataFormat.Json (see working code below). Maybe this is useful for someone else

```
var client = new RestClient(@"http://localhost:9000/?properties={""annotators"":""tokenize,ssplit,pos"", ""outputFormat"":""json""}")
{
    Timeout = 5000 
};

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST)
{
    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};
request.AddBody(@"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
var response = client.Execute(request);
```